# Convert Windows path for Windows Ubuntu Bash

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a windows batch script that uses Windows Ubuntu Bash. It receives a full Windows path as an argument and then passes that path to a command in Ubuntu Bash.

```
@echo off
bash -lic 'ffmpeg -i "%1" output.avi'
```

Here `"%1"` is the full Windows path, like `"C:\some path\file.avi"`

The command gives the error:

```
C:some pathfile.avi: Protocol not found
```

What can I do to have this Windows path convert to a path like `/mnt/c/some\ path/file.avi` which the Windows Bash would actually understand?

Comment: What you need is replacing all occurences of `C:` with `/mnt/c` (potentially for other drive letters, too), right?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Windows Build 17046 **[[1]](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/releases/tag/17046)** contains new `wslpath` utility that can translate paths from/to WSL/Windows. This was known missing WSL feature. **[[2]](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/522)**

Example usage:

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash

$ which wslpath
/bin/wslpath

$ wslpath -a 'C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\foo.zip'
/mnt/c/aaa/bbb/ccc/foo.zip
```

You can call `wslpath` from Powershell on Windows:

```
>>> wsl wslpath -a 'C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\foo.zip'
/mnt/c/aaa/bbb/ccc/foo.zip
```

`wslpath` options and parameters:

```
-a    force result to absolute path format
-u    translate from a Windows path to a WSL path (default)
-w    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path
-m    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path, with ‘/’ instead of ‘\\’
```

Comment: For older Windows, available here: https://github.com/laurent22/wslpath

Comment: posh needs escaping '\', but wsl not. your example `$ wslpath -a 'C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\foo.zip'` should be `$ wslpath -a 'C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\foo.zip'` It works when escaped, but useless escaping is confusing. One could assume it must be escaped. Also, I think description on `-m`, `... with ‘/’ instead of ‘\\’` should have one ‘\’ (I know it's copy-pasted) If you do `wslpath -w /mnt/c/Users`, it does not print two ‘\\’

Comment: I believe that `wslpath` is *part* of the answer, but I believe that this post does not functionally answer the question — which asks, when a batch file has a Windows-style (`C:\foo\bar\blah`) name for a data file, how does it run a WSL command on that file?

Comment: @papo I have just stumbled upon a problem with usescaped slashes: it is inconsistent and depends on how is it run, when run from powershell it just omits unescaped slashes, when run from bash it treats them correctly only inside of a string.

Comment: @sukhmel true, in wsl (on which bash for windows runs) and also in cmd console, either put path in single or double quotes, or escape as \\ The unneccesity of escaping inside quotes offers a fast way of doing: `cat \`wslpath '` then drag&drop a file into the console and finish the line: `'\``

Comment: @sukhmel Powershell is interpreting your path string before passing it to `wsl`. Wrap it in double quotes to avoid that issue. It's a common problem throughout Windows when passing strings between commands. The example would become this in Powershell: `wsl wslpath -a "'C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\foo.zip'"`

Comment: Caveat 2021: Unix `wslpath` does not remove carriage returns. So you must do it manually, e.g.: `export WHOME=$(wslpath -a $(cmd.exe /c echo %HOME%) | tr -d '\r')`

Comment: How to call `wslpath` with a variable which I can't escape?
I have a powershell script with line `wsl wslpath -a "$PSScriptRoot"` and it returns `wslpath: C:Folder1Folder2`

Comment: How do we make this work from a batch file where the filename is not double-backslashed?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a bat file to do this. Just place the file wherever you are working or add it to your path (or just put it above your code, which would be easier to work with). Remember to assign "variable" to your file path first (if you are using a separate file, try using parameters).

What the code does:

1) Get the first letter of the path, which is the drive.

2) Remove the first two letters.

3) Change the slashes.

4) This is the tricky part: since Linux is case sensitive, we need to convert uppercase drive letter to lowercase. Do this by matching each (tell me if there is a better way). You can remove unnecessary drive letters too, since you probably have no more than ten drives.

5) Combine everything to give the final string.

The result:

Input:

```
E:\myfiles\app1\data\file.csv
```

Output (with the quotation marks):

```
"/mnt/e/myfiles/app1/data/file.csv"
```

The code is as follows:

```
@echo OFF

set "variable=E:\myfiles\app1\data\file.csv"

set "drive=%variable:~0,1%"

set variable=%variable:~2%
set "variable=%variable:\=/%"

if %drive%==A set "drive=a"
if %drive%==B set "drive=b"
if %drive%==C set "drive=c"
if %drive%==D set "drive=d"
if %drive%==E set "drive=e"
if %drive%==F set "drive=f"
if %drive%==G set "drive=g"
if %drive%==H set "drive=h"
if %drive%==I set "drive=i"
if %drive%==J set "drive=j"
if %drive%==K set "drive=k"
if %drive%==L set "drive=l"
if %drive%==M set "drive=m"
if %drive%==N set "drive=n"
if %drive%==O set "drive=o"
if %drive%==P set "drive=p"
if %drive%==Q set "drive=q"
if %drive%==R set "drive=r"
if %drive%==S set "drive=s"
if %drive%==T set "drive=t"
if %drive%==U set "drive=u"
if %drive%==V set "drive=v"
if %drive%==W set "drive=w"
if %drive%==X set "drive=x"
if %drive%==Y set "drive=y"
if %drive%==Z set "drive=z"

set "variable=/mnt/%drive%%variable%"

echo "%variable%"

@echo ON
```

Comment: What about the reverse, converting a Unix path to a Windows path in a shell script?

Comment: @JacobTheDev, you would need only slight modifications for that ;)

Comment: actually figured it out this morning! https://gist.github.com/JacobDB/e71e22c3663175b2369211aeb54362fe

Comment: What is the advantage of your code over wlspath? Why not powershell, but old-school?

Comment: @Timo see the date of the answer :)

Comment: This works properly with paths that are do not have the double backslash. This is the only solution that achieves what the OP is asking for. 

I simplified it using bash with tr to convert uppercase to lowercase instead of all the if statements with: "for /f %%i in ('bash -c "echo %drive% |  tr \"[A-Z]\" \"[a-z]\""') do set lowerDrive=%%i"

Answer (score 5):

Why so complicated?

Change the registry entry

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\bash.exe\shell\open\command
```

from

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe "%1"
```

to

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe `wslpath '%1'`
```

Use backticks before wslpath and at the end, and use single quotation marks (straight ticks) around %1.

Works for me.

Comment: Really?  This solves the problem in the question, where `bash` is called from a batch file? (Note that, in the example, bash’s first argument is `-lic`, so it’s not clear to me how `wslpath '%1'` is going to work.) And why have you changed from double quotes (`"%1"`) to single quotes (`'%1'`)?

Comment: Plus one, I like it.

Answer (score 3):

This simple solution works for files on the `C` drive:

```
@echo off
set X=%1
set X=%X:\=/%
set X=%X:C:=/mnt/c%
bash -lic 'ffmpeg -i "%X%" output.avi'
```

Answer (score 3):

this is my cdwin script, change win dir to wsl path

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$(sed -e 's~\\~/~g' -e "s/\([CD]\):/\L\1/" -e "s/^/\/mnt\//g" <<< "$1")
cd $line
```

Use:

```
#:cdwin 'C:\Users\win\Documents'
#:/mnt/c/Users/win/Documents$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the cygpath tool:

Unix to windows:
$ cygpath -w /d/temp
D:\temp

Windows to unix:
$ cygpath -u 'D:\temp'
/d/temp

https://dev.to/taijidude/paths-conversion-in-git-bash-3jeh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).